# Bitbake: Is there a way to build all dependencies of an image recipe, but skip the actual image creation itself?

Tags: dependencies, gitlab-ci, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have a Yocto project that I’m building in a GitLab pipeline. For reasons (parallel toolchain for FPGA build) I’ve had to split the build into two pipeline jobs.

The first job does a full image build but with a variable set to
disable the FPGA install recipe (since there’s no FPGA file available at this time). This builds everything and stores results in the SSTATE cache (external from the GitLab runner - on a NFS volume mount, because I actually have multiple co-located runners).

The second job, which runs once the FPGA file is available, some time later, performs the same build but with the FPGA install recipe enabled, so that the FPGA file ends up in the final image. This is much faster than the first job because it retrieves most of the packages from the SSTATE cache, courtesy of the first job.

I should note that because it’s GitLab and running in Docker executor there’s no sharing of bitbake workspace between these jobs, so I rely on the SSTATE cache to carry state to the second job.

My issue is that the image created by the first job is basically useless, since it is missing the FPGA file. It is thrown away. But it still took time to create the image. All I really needed from that first job is for the dependencies to be built and cached.

So my question is - is it possible to set up bitbake such that it will build all of an image’s dependencies, but not the actual image recipe itself?

Comment: I am not getting why you need to build the first image in first place? If you have the cache already there, why don't just building the second image? Or can you clarify more your question. Because nothing relates between `not the actual image itself` and the `second image` stuff.

Comment: Between builds, there is an XSA file (hardware definition) that invalidates some of the cached packages, which is why the first build is required. This basically warms up the cache for the second build. I want to avoid actually building the image in the first build though, as that’s never cached anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Yocto to build only the dependencies of a recipe.

This is confirmed by the Yocto developers themselves (In live [IRC](https://web.libera.chat/?channels=#yocto) chat):

> Not sure there is an easy way to build only dependencies

But I thought about a way to do it that you can try:

You can generate a dependencies graph for your recipe using:

```bash
bitbake -g <recipe>
```

this will generate two files:

- pn-buildlist
- task-depends.dot

`pn-buildlist` is the list of all recipes that the main recipe depends on `DEPENDS`, and `task-depends.dot` is a detailed relations between those dependencies, you don't need the latter.

So, you can try looping through `pn-buildlist` and `bitbake` each recipe in there.

But you need to take note that it will contain the recipe name as first line, so you need to remove it:

```bash
# Remove the recipe from the dependencies file
recipe="core-image-minimal"
sed -i "/$recipe/d" pn-buildlist

# Loop and build dependencies
while read recipe; do bitbake $recipe; done < pn-buildlist
```

I tried this with adding `aaa` as a recipe example to `IMAGE_INSTALL` and it gets added to `pn-buildlist`.

- **NOTE**:

If you want to do it with a simple recipe (not an image recipe), `pn-buildlist` will only hold the `DEPENDS` content.

Comment: That seems like a good option, I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe its a more efficient option to gather the list of dependencies first, and call bitbake once with the list of recipes, instead of calling bitbake over and over.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding below line

> unset do_image[noexec]

in the image recipes. It will perform all the tasks except **do_image** task